# arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, g++, toolchain, linaro

I am newbie to develope for Linux and recently stumbled upon this error `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++: No such file or directory`.

I tried to fix the error which came while I was following the code from [this](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=297335) thread: in line `make -j4`.

Having looked for `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++` over internet had no result. I also downloaded the `gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.04-20130417_linux` and added it to the PATH but couldn't find `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++` in bin directory.

Comment: Where from did you get your ```toolchain```?

Comment: It does not contain ```g++```. Try to get from [Arm GNU Toolchain Downloads](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjA0er_5bSEAxUHTaQEHQuIAzkQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.arm.com%2Fdownloads%2F-%2Farm-gnu-toolchain-downloads&usg=AOvVaw0SpQgSWn-HABEh6BQEYQYw&opi=89978449)

Comment: The toolchain was downloaded from the [link](https://github.com/kobolabs/Kobo-Reader/blob/master/toolchain/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.04-20130417_linux.tar.bz2)

Comment: If you dont mind, would you please give an exact link of the file. I am finding it difficult to choose one.

Comment: ```AArch32 GNU/Linux target with hard float (arm-none-linux-gnueabihf)``` if your native machine is ```aarch``` or ```AArch32 GNU/Linux target with hard float (arm-none-linux-gnueabihf)``` if your native machine is ```x64-86```

Comment: Is your native machine `aarch` or `x64-86`?

Comment: A compiler from 2013. Yuck. If you picked this one simply because it was what you found, I strongly recommend you keep looking. Perhaps you can get something more suitable from your OS's package manager.